# Magento 2 : How to Get Shipping Quote (Shipping Calculator) on Product Page

Tags: magento2, product, shipping, quote

I want to display the Estimate Shipping and Tax section on the product page in Magento 2.

Any guide how can I achieve this? I don't need the code but If you can provide any guidelines that will be really appreciated.

Comment: Hey, anyone has idea about this?Please let me know If there is any extension available.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add this to your product view you would need to create a new extension which does the search based on a custom form param

Comment: can you please give me any extension link , or little suggestion how to create the extension for shipping quote?

Comment: do you have any suggestion for the extension which provides this thing?

Comment: hello guys, is there any way to display Estimate Shipping and Tax  on the product page? Please give me some proper suggestion in details.

Comment: You would need to have it created bespokly for your needs.